# Is $\int\frac{\mathrm d \, x}{x^2-1}= \operatorname{arctanh} ~x + C = \operatorname{arccoth} ~x + K$ correct?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

My professor gave us an integral but I think it's incorrect.
Is this correct?

$$
\DeclareMathOperator\arctanh{arctanh}
\DeclareMathOperator\arccoth{arccoth}
\int\frac{\mathrm d \, x}{x^2-1}= \arctanh ~x + C = \arccoth ~x + K$$

Comment: You can use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) for such verifications.

Comment: Well first of all, there should be a $+C$

Comment: and second we get $$-arctanh(x)+C$$

Comment: @WiCK3DPOiSON i tried but i don't know how to do it :(

Comment: @Sarah type in `integral of dx/(x^2-1)` ... Wolfram Alpha is pretty forgiving.

Comment: You can check by taking the derivatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that

> $$\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}\ \mathrm dx= \operatorname{artanh}(x)+C$$

For the posted integral we have
$$\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}\ \mathrm dx=-\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}\ \mathrm dx $$
$$=-\operatorname{artanh}(x)+C$$
So no, the stated equality is not correct. It's possible that either you or your professor, may have gotten mixed up.

Answer (score 3):

$\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} \,dx = \operatorname{arctanh} x + c$

Also,

$\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} \,dx = \operatorname{arccoth} x + c$

If you are writing as written above then change 1 into -1.

Or $\int \frac{1}{x^2-1} \,dx = -\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} \,dx -\operatorname{arctanh} x + c$

Comment: @Sarah its not good. You accepted my answer and then unaccepted it. My answer and the new accepted answer has same explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to rewrite $\DeclareMathOperator\arctanh{arctanh}\DeclareMathOperator\arccoth{arccoth} \arccoth x$ as an inverse function. In this case, let $f(x)=\coth x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}$. To determine the inverse, just solve for $x$ in the equation $y=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}$.

\begin{align*}
y&=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}\\
e^{2x}y-y&=e^{2x}+1\\
e^{2x}(y-1)&=y+1\\
e^{2x}&=\frac{y+1}{y-1}\\
2x&=\ln\left(\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right)\\
x&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right)\\
\arccoth x&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)
\end{align*}
You will get something similar for $\arctanh x$!
\begin{equation*}
\arctanh x=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)
\end{equation*}
For the integral, use partial fractions. The rewrite is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|\right)+C
\end{equation*}

Your lecturer was close! for $|x|>1$, we have $\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}\mathrm{d}x=-\arccoth x+C$ and for $|x|<1$, we have $\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}\mathrm{d}x=-\arctanh x+C$.

I hope this helps (and is all correct)!

Answer (score 1):

By definition,

$$\text{arcoth }x=\text{artanh }\frac1x.$$

Then taking the derivative,

$$\text{arcoth }'x=-\frac1{x^2}\text{artanh }'\frac1x==-\frac1{x^2}\frac1{1-\dfrac1{x^2}}=\frac1{x^2-1}.$$

so there is a sign error.